# How to go through each object in oData?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, object, each

[image: How go through each object in oData?]

when i type the following code statement i get the image attached.Now i want to access the property "label" that is inside each of these objects. how can i go through each of these objects and get their "label" properties?

```
item.getModel().oData;
```

i have tried the following code but it failed to work:

```
               var labelText = item.getModel().oData;

                labelText.forEach(function(entry) {
                    var c = entry.StreetName;
                });
```

An example of one of the items:

[image: The object info expanded]

Answer (score 0):

Because it's an `Object` and not an `Array`, you should use `Object.keys` or some other method to access each property of the object instead. For example:

```
var labelText = item.getModel().oData;
var keys = Object.keys(labelText);
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    var c = labelText[keys[i]].StreetName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A succinct way of iterating properties of an object, usisng `forEach` and the `keys` method of `Object`

```
var labelText = item.getModel().oData;

Object.keys(labelText).forEach(function(entryName) {
    var c = labelText[entryName].StreetName;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var labelText = item.getModel().oData;

                $(labelText).each(function(index,entry) {
                    var c = entry.StreetName;
                });
```

Comment: I have attached an image with the expanded view of the object

Comment: then iterate deeper..
$(labelText).each(function(index,entry) {
                    $(entry).each(function(i,e){
                           alert(e.StreetName);
                     });
                });

Comment: it returns e.streetName is undefined. "e" is still a listof objects

Comment: both entry and e are the same thing